# Sanitization with Javascript and jQuery: Escaping quotes and double quotes automatically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sanitization

Does there exist some ready command for escaping quotes without creating quote-mess? Suppose I source [1] type of code-block and I don't want to edit it at all -- some command to handle the sanitization so not intercepting with the rest of the code?

```
<div id='p'>
        <div id='pp'></div>
        <div id='ppp'></div>
</div>

<script>
        $('div.pp').html('INSERT 1: both quotes, fails, without escaping')
</script>

 [1]  <a href="..."><img src='. fails,needs escaping..'></a>
```

Comment: Where does the HTML code `[1]` come from? Is it hard-coded in a HTML document? Or a data base?

Answer (score 2):

Avoid quote-mess by having this convention:

- use double quotes for attribute values in HTML code
- use single quotes for string literals in JavaScript code

HTML:

```
<div id="p">
    <div id="pp"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( '#pp' ).html( '<a href="..."><img src="..."></a>' );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/HqrSz/